# What reasons would an Android Phone's Network Radio turn off Sporadically

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have an android phone that is experiencing an issue that I suspect is hardware related. Randomly, service will no longer work on the phone and the only way I have found to temporarily resolve the issue is to dial `*#*#4636#*#*` and manually turn the radio back on. This will restore functionality, but only temporarily. It seems to be indeterminate when it stop working again.

I can't think of a good methodology to pinpoint the issue, so any insight would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to turn on immediately by your manual method, then it seems to be a software issue.

Did you try a factory reset? It resolves most of software issues.

Comment: I did perform a factory reset and that solved the issue. But in the same way an amputation fixes a hangnail.

I'm still curious what exactly was happening.

Comment: Software issues are random and may come up anytime, Especially when there are loopholes (which are many in case of Android, Reference: https://www.scmp.com/tech/social-gadgets/article/1835424/security-loopholes-android-os-social-media-putting-550m-users)
So, These loopholes are main reason of such random problems and these are usually fixed by a factory reset.